# WaterMark in Crystal report VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

How to create watermark text box in Crystal Reports vb.net 2012?
Have to create class for that? Please send me a sample of code or procedure on how to do that.. Thank you very much..

its just like the word "CONFIDENTIAL" in my sample image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding watermark is simply need to setting [here](http://victoriayudin.com/2009/05/05/adding-watermarks-to-crystal-reports/) is article.

Answer (score 1):

While the above link is the most common and straight forward way of adding a watermark. 
However its a bit of a pain if you want the watermark to be **Diagonally across the page**. Crystal wont let you do that unless you embed an image.

Also if you have lines and boxes (such as columns) on your report, the watermark will be overlapping those lines if you use the above solution.

The best solution I have used is using a Subreport:

1. On the Main report add the watermark to the section and select Underlay
   following sections for that section.
2. On the subreport add your
   tables and lines that would normally go on your Details sections.
3. Then put this Subreport on the Details section of the Main report.
4. Voila!! The lines and watermark will display exactly as you want and be under your control.

Hope it helps someone else.